# Define default TTTabItem in a TTTabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, tabbar, tabitem

Hi all
Does anyone know how to set the default TTTabItem in an TTTabBar? I was able to load the corresponding page as default, but I am not able to check an item as default in the TTTabBar list.

Sofar, always the first TTTabItem is checked.

Thanks and best regards,
Doonot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger default = 0;
[self tabBar:_tabBar tabSelected:default];
```